# Cargar componente en función de resultado de otro componente Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un componente que hace una llamada via POST con ajax de jquery y se trae una variable (data), en función de esta, me gustaría poder cargar el resto de componentes que formarán la página. El problema me lo da cuando le pongo el navigate en el  success de ajax. Si lo pongo en cualquier otro componente si funciona.

**Componente Login**

```
import { Component, OnInit,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-login',
  templateUrl: './api-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css']
})

export class ApiLoginComponent implements OnInit {
  url: string; 
    constructor(private router: Router){
      this.url="https://angular/php/login.php"
      this.login();
    }

ngOnInit() {} 


login(){ 
  var parametros = {
        "usuario": "PrecaNuevo",
        "clave": "PrecaNuevo",
    };

    $.ajax({ 
        data: parametros,
    url: this.url,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        this.router.navigate(['/cabecera']); **//Aqui redirecciono y falla**
    }
  });
}

}
```

Comment: Hola, ¿estás utilizando rutas para tús componentes?

Comment: Buenas, no se lo que es exactamente pero creo que no. Se trata de hacer un login y se la respuesta ajax me da 1 ejecutar el resto de componentes. Creo que no uso rutas

Comment: Te recomiendo mires éste tutorial https://codingpotions.com/angular-login-sesion/ te puede ser utilidad, las rutas son las urls ejemplo app/login, app/inicio, dependiendo de éstas rutas podrás renderizar a o b componente.

Answer (score 0):

La solución ha sido esta:
`const that = this;` en el metodo `login();`

Aun no se por que se tiene que hacer así pero se que así funciona.
EL código seria el siguiente.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Identifiers, identifierModuleUrl } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-login',
  templateUrl: './api-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css']
})


export class ApiLoginComponent implements OnInit {
  usuario: String="";
  clave: String="";
  url: string; 
  display: String;


  constructor(public router: Router){ 
    this.url="https://p/angular/php/login.php"
    this.display="block";
  }

ngOnInit() {
} //Similiar al onload o document ready


closeModal(){
  this.display='none';
}


login(usuario, clave){ //Metodo

  this.usuario=usuario.value;
  this.clave=clave.value;
  const that = this;
  var parametros = {
        "usuario": this.usuario,
        "clave": this.clave,
    };

    $.ajax({ //Llamo a la funcion 
        data: parametros,
    url: this.url,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
      if(data==1){ //Identificado
       that.router.navigate(['/principal']); //Muestro todos los componentes de la web.
      that.display='none'; //Oculto el formulario
      }

    }
  });
}


}
```

Comment: Mezclar jQuery con Angular no suele ser una buena idea, te aconsejo aprender sobre los servicios en Angular y sobre cómo gestionar con observables los eventos, como pueda ser una llamada AJAX

Comment: Gracias por el consejo Pablo, el tema es que jquery hace extremadamente mas facil ese tipo de acciones que angular,  pero tienes razón, tendré que aprender tarde o temprano

Comment: *Parece* más fácil, pero en cuanto tengas que orquestar el comportamiento de varios componentes a la vez, dejará de serlo.